# I'd used MediaController, but how can show mediacontroll bar and set play pause?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

I'd used MediaController, but how can show mediacontroll bar and set play pause?

I change to use this code, but the video will auto play and not control bar can use.

So how could called control bar and set play, pause and not auto play video?

```
holder.videoView.setVideoPath(postModel.getPostimage());
                holder.videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(mContext));
                holder.videoView.requestFocus();
                holder.videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
                                mediaController = new MediaController(mContext);
                                holder.videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
                                mediaController.setAnchorView(holder.videoView);
                                ((ViewGroup) mediaController.getParent()).removeView(mediaController);
                                mediaController.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                holder.playButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });
                        holder.videoView.start();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: It might help you https://medium.com/fungjai/playing-video-by-exoplayer-b97903be0b33

Comment: @monabaharlou I'd updated my context, can u check it? please